# No DbContext found in Console App using EF Core dotnet EF migration add results in No DbContext found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

Please note this is a CONSOLE app.

**The Problem**
When using dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context Efc.Models.ApplicationDbContext I receive
the following message: "No DbContext named 'Efc.Models.ApplicationDbContext' found"

I am running the dotnet command in the EFConsole.ConUI directory. The spellings seem to be correct.

Using VS2019, EntityFramework Core 3.1.3

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=SSSSSSSS\XXSQLSERVER;Database=PhoneNumberTest;User ID=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX");
        }
```

The following packages are installed as indicated:

***EFConsole.ConUI Console project***

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

**Efc.Models -- class library for models and ApplicationDbContext**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

**Efc.RepositoryLayer -- class library for the repositories.**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

If I move the ApplicationDbContext to the EFConsole.ConUI project the dotnet ef command works. But for obvious reasons the ApplicationDbContext needs to be in a separate project so that it can be referenced from the Efc.Repository project at a minimum.

**EDIT:**
Note:  Because this is a console APP I do not have a Startup class and I have not loaded any services like one would in a WebApp in its Startup class.  Could this be the problem??

I have searched and read until my eyes were bleeding. :(

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the Nuget Package Manager Console:
In Visual Studio: Tools -> NuGet Package Manager => Package Manager Console

Select the default project to the one where the DbContext class is:
[image]

Run the command:

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```

Comment: Kebek, thanks for the suggestion. I ran the command in the Package Manager Console with the same results. No DbObject found. I am suspicious that because I do not have any services defined and don't have a Startup class like in a WebApp that that is the problem.